# Android Studio : Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, dex

When I started to build the app I get this error

> Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$1;

This is the dependencies I have in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    /* compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }*/
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

    compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please help me out on this issue, it's a critical issue recent days I have been into it.

Comment: Try adding the below to dependencies tag in build.gradle >>> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

Comment: Hi manokar did you check my answer below